# unable to get SharePoint site properties to implement property tag in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, developer, development

Implementing property bag to change Project description of site collection with below code ,But finding no luck.

Can any one help me in knowing what went wrong in my below code

```
SPSite mysite = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;<br>
SPWeb myweb = mysite.RootWeb;<br>
var mybag = myweb.AllProperties;<br>
mybag["Description"] = "SharePoint Training";<br>
myweb.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to update property bag.

Try the below code:

```
SPSite mysite = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
SPWeb myweb = mysite.RootWeb;
myweb.Description = "SharePoint Training";
myweb.Update();
```